# Jenkins "options.provider is required to create a new pkgcloud client" error

Tags: mongodb, jenkins, server, automation, devops

I am currently setting up Jenkins for my server.
I installed pkgcloud module through npm and now I'm getting the following error :

```
 Error: options.provider is required to create a new pkgcloud client.
```

Some logs :

```
 1) "before all" hook: global before
(node:55096) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
After all, removing temp directories...
./temp removed.
./data removed.

  0 passing (983ms)
  1 failing

  1)  "before all" hook: global before:
     Error: options.provider is required to create a new pkgcloud client.
    at Object.pkgcloud.(anonymous function).createClient (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/node_modules/pkgcloud/lib/pkgcloud.js:83:13)
    at new Imager (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/.jenkins/node_modules/imager/lib/imager.js:43:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app/routes/uploads.js:7:14)
    at Module.load (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at module.exports (app/routes.js:18:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:155:27)
    at Module.load (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Context.<anonymous> (tests/helper.js:43:16)
```

Will appreciate any help since I couldnt find answer online.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution :

The issue was that I did not do npm install before grunt.